# How to duplicate data in table using view?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I duplicate data in table using view?

I've created the view:

```
create view region as select region_id, region_name from regions;
```

regions contains only mentioned columns and now I was trying to do this:

```
insert into region values (region);
```

But I got error

> 947. 00000 -  "not enough values"

If my view provides 2 columns should be enough to fill in 2 columns.

To be more clear, now I got

```
table regions:
region_id | region_name
-----------------------
         1| abc
         2| def
```

and I want this

```
table regions:
region_id | region_name
-----------------------
         1| abc
         2| def
         1| abc
         2| def
```

Comment: Try including *both* columns in the insert.  The error message seems pretty clear.  The error message seems quite clear.

Comment: Is region_id auto generated column? What is your plan to fill region_id?  Even your values clause is also incorrect.

Comment: i have created view region so if I  `select * from region` i get 2 columns but even if I put whole expression to `values()` then i got _missing expression_ error, dont got it why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
insert into region
select * from region
```

Or if its a view and you want to duplicate the values in execution time, you can do:

```
select r.*
  from region r,
       (select 1 from dual connect by level <= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't providing the `region_id` (e.g., it's autogenerated), you to explicitly state what columns you are providing in the `insert` statement:

```sql
insert into region (region_name) values ('some_region');
-- Here -----------^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the table and view:

```sql
CREATE TABLE regions ( region_id INT, region_name VARCHAR2(20) );
create view region as select region_id, region_name from regions;
```

Then you can name the column you are inserting into and wrap the value in single quotes to show it is a string literal. Like this:

```sql
insert into region (region_name) values ('region');
```

If you do not include the column names then you need to provide a value for every column:

```sql
insert into region values ( 2, 'region2');
```

Or, if you want a variable named `region` rather than a string literal then you can use PL/SQL to define the variable:

```sql
DECLARE
  region REGIONS.REGION_NAME%TYPE := 'abc';
BEGIN
  insert into region (region_name) values (region);
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM region;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> REGION_ID | REGION_NAME
> --------: | :----------
>      null | region     
>         2 | region2    
>      null | abc
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dece5fb907ed423e0ff4b501875dab80)*

---

> all i want is to duplicate content of regions table using region view

You can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO region
SELECT * FROM region;
```

or:

```sql
INSERT INTO region ( region_id, region_name )
SELECT * FROM region;
```

or:

```sql
INSERT INTO region ( region_id, region_name )
SELECT region_id, region_name FROM region;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM region;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> REGION_ID | REGION_NAME
> --------: | :----------
>      null | region     
>         2 | region2    
>      null | abc        
>      null | region     
>         2 | region2    
>      null | abc
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f618e53c1987d6c1e5d972ff00ec62be)*

Comment: ok, but this `insert into region (region_id, region_name) values (select * from region);` doesn't seem to work fine either and all i want is to duplicate content of _regions_ table using _region_ view but maby its not possible to have 2 identical rows?

Comment: Thank You! , So it was all about extra brackets i used :D

Comment: @TomSevet Almost, there are 2 versions of `INSERT`. You were using a single-row insert which is the format `INSERT INTO table_name ( [columns,...] ) VALUES ( [values,...] )` and the second is the multi-row insert which is the format `INSERT INTO table_name ( [columns,...] ) SELECT [values,...] FROM table_name`. You didn't want the `VALUES` keyword as well as the brackets.